# Mysql отключается при создании больше 3 хостов

Tags: mysql, python, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Использую django + gunicorn + supervisor + mysql
Создаю 5 хостов на разных портах. 8000 8001 8002 8003 8005
БД Mysql отключается после включения 4 портов. На трех работает. С чем связано? Пробовал сменить порт, не работает.

Comment: вопрос очень невнятно сформулирован. что такое «хосты на портах»? при чём тут программа supervisor? вы пытаетесь запустить пять экземпляров mysqld? что значит «mysql отключается»? что пишет в лог программа mysqld?

Comment: Я запускаю 5 виртуальных серверов с помощью gunicorn + supervisord   На каждом есть отдельный проект. Но только 2 проекта подключены к базе данных mysql. Другие с ней никак не связаны. Но когда я запускаю все 5 серверов командой sudo supervisorctl start app_name, то доступ к базе прекращается. Перезапускаю базу, выдает ошибку. Когда останавливаю 2 другие, работает.

Comment: Банально не хватало оперативной памяти...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL стандартно запускается на порту 3306, его можно поменять в конф. файле my.cnf (my.ini), но обычно в этом нет смысла. Есть подозрение, что речь идет про недоступность базы после определенного кол-ва подключений к ней. Тогда нужно менять настройку максимального кол-ва подключений

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404374/how-do-i-increase-the-mysql-connections-for-my-server